# Search in Domino Database is not working

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I am using Domino Data service to access documents based on certain search criteria.One of my document is

{
    "@href":"/rrdb.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/2FC3551DC5266A5088257E35001D5D2C",
    "@unid":"2FC3551DC5266A5088257E35001D5D2C",
    "@noteid":"922",
    "@created":"2015-04-28T05:20:43Z",
    "@modified":"2015-04-28T05:20:47Z",
    "@authors":
    ["CN=domain/O=test",""
    ],
    "@form":"Reservation",
    "ApptUNID":"B0E582BBA2A39B5988257E35001D5D29",
    "From":"CN=ram/O=test",
    "AltFrom":"CN=ram/O=test",
    "Chair":"CN=ram/O=test",
    "AltChair":"CN=ram/O=test",
    "Principal":"CN=ram/O=cisco",
    "SequenceNum":1,
    "ORGState":"5",
    "ResourceType":"1",
    "ResourceName":"Sedna/B17",
    "Room":"Sedna/B17@test",
    "Capacity":1,
    "_ViewIcon":133,
    "AppointmentType":"3",
    "StartTimeZone":"Z=-3005$DO=0$ZN=India",
    "EndTimeZone":"Z=-3005$DO=0$ZN=India",
    "Topic":"2 hour meeting with sendna conference room",
    "SendTo":"CN=Sedna/O=B17",
    "PostedDate":"2015-04-28T05:20:43Z",
    "Encrypt":"0",
    "Categories":"",
    "RouteServers":"CN=B16-PF-QA-055/O=test",
    "RouteTimes":
    ["2015-04-28T05:20:43Z","2015-04-28T05:20:44Z"
    ],
    "DeliveredDate":"2015-04-28T05:20:44Z",
    "StartDate":"2015-04-28T05:15:00Z",
    "StartTime":"2015-04-28T05:15:00Z",
    "StartDateTime":"2015-04-28T05:15:00Z",
    "EndDate":"2015-04-28T07:15:00Z",
    "EndTime":"2015-04-28T07:15:00Z",
    "EndDateTime":"2015-04-28T07:15:00Z",
    "UpdateSeq":1,
    "Author":"CN=ram/O=test",
    "ResourceOwner":"",
    "ReservedFor":"CN=ram/O=cisco",
    "ReservedBy":"CN=ram/O=cisco",
    "RQStatus":"A",
    "Purpose":"2 hour meeting with sendna conference room",
    "NoticeType":"A",
    "Step":3,
    "Site":"B17",
    "ReserveDate":"2015-04-28T05:15:00Z"
}

I am using http://{host}/rrdb.nsf/api/data/collections/name/$Calendar?search=([SendTo] CONTAINS "CN=Sedna") to fetch this document,But it is not returning me the record.But if i use CONTAINS "Sedna" then it works.

Answer (score 3):

[edited]
The internal representation of the sendTo seems to be [ABBREVIATE] and not [CANONICALIZE]. Thus looking for **CN=**... doesn't return any result, since the CN= O= are not part of the data.

Replace the search by:

```
[SendTo]="Sedna/B17"
```

Or optionally "Sedna/" if you only want to test that exact name is Sedna.

Comment: With quotes it is not returning any result but without it is giving "message":"Notes error: Query is not understandable" Error.

Comment: Another idea replace equal by question mark:[SendTo]="*CN?Sedna*"

Comment: No luck.It is not returning any response.

Comment: Strange, could it be that the internal storing is canonical ? please try [SendTo]="Sedna/B17" and also [SendTo]="Sedna/"